# Fail safe assertions in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macros

I commonly use assertions in Objective-C where I want to assert a value. On a  debug build I assert in order to stop execution of the program and check if my assumption was incorrect. However, on production builds I find a way to fail safely in a way to minimise the user impact. I achieve this by creating a macro that encapsulates an NSAssert within an if statement which also executes the code I would like to run as a failsafe on production. For example:

An assertion macro I would use:

```
#define AssertTrueOrExecute(condition, action) \
  if (!condition) { \
    NSAssert(testCondition, @"Condition failed"); \
    action; \
  }
```

Somewhere in my application I would have something like this:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  BOOL testCondition = ...
  // Ensure the testCondition is true before proceeding any further
  AssertTrueOrExecute(testCondition, return);
  // Potentially unsafe code that never gets executed if testCondition is false
}

- (void)someReturningMethod
{
  BOOL testCondition = ...
  // Ensure the testCondition is true before proceeding any further
  AssertTrueOrExecute(testCondition, return @"safe string");
  // Potentially unsafe code that never gets executed if testCondition is false
}
```

Since I cannot define a macro like the one mention in Swift, is there a way to have the same behaviour? That is how would I go about having a Swift equivalent for my `AssertTrueOrExecute` macro?

**Update:**

To further explain the question, if I was using Swift I currently would write something like this:

```
func someMethod () {
    let testCondition : Bool = ...

    // Ensure the testCondition is true before proceeding any further
    if (!testCondition) {
      assert(testCondition);
      return;
    }
    // Potentially unsafe code that never gets executed if testCondition is false
}
```

So the question is more along the lines of how can the if statement with the assertions be wrapped in a similar way I have the Objective-C macro so that I can assert or return early for example?

**Update 2:**

Another example would be in function that returns something, for example:

```
func someReturningMethod () -> String {
    let testCondition : Bool = ...

    // Ensure the testCondition is true before proceeding any further
    if (!testCondition) {
      assert(testCondition);
      return "safe string";
    }    
    // Potentially unsafe code that never gets executed if testCondition is false
    return "some other string"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no macros in Swift, but there could be other means in Swift where you could achieve this same functionality as it is possible in Objective-C.

However, the real issue here is, that you try to approach a problem in a way which you really shouldn't:

Do not mix *programmer errors* and *runtime errors*!

Instead, make a clear distinction what *programmer errors* are and what *runtime errors* are. Handle programmer errors with assertions, and handle runtime errors with `NSError` respectively in Swift with `try` & `catch` and `throw`.

Note, that the "scope" of a programmer error is not restricted to the point when the program fails through an assertion failure: Very likely such an error has bad side effects which leave the program in an invalid state, and often this assertion detects errors that may have occurred possibly a long time before the assertion failed. So, when an assertion fails, your program is very likely already in an invalid state.

A rule of thumb is, that an assertion failure should not happen in production code (read MUST NOT). Well, these are *programmer errors* and should be fixed, shouldn't they? You verify your assumptions using assertions in unit tests. If you still fear, that your assumption may break in production and are also sure that this is not a runtime error (which should always be handled gracefully), it should stop the program - all bets are off anyway. In Swift, you can use `fatalError` for this.

Sometimes, the distinction whether the violation of a certain assumption is a programmer error or whether it's a runtime error is not always that obvious and may depend on the context. As a programmer, though, you can always *define* what it is. Take a string parameter as example: if you obtain it directly from a text field from a user input who wants to create an account and is asked for his name, you should validate the string and return/throw an error if it doesn't fit your expectation - for example if it is empty, too short etc. That is, in Swift you may `throw` an error and handle that gracefully on the call-site, possibly in a View Controller. On the other hand, you *define* that it would not make sense to initialise a `User` object whose `name` will be empty. That is, in your init routine you *define* the precondition that a valid user name must not be empty, and you check this with `assert` or `fatalError`. In this scenario your program is correct, when there is no code path which initialises a User whose name is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although this may not be the answer I was looking for it does provide a lot of insight in terms of the approach to error handling. I use assertions to catch programmer errors but given the type safety in Swift it may be the case that I have fewer errors to catch anyways. My experience with Swift is very limited at this point so even though I may disagree with the the fact that sometimes it is possible to fail gracefully on programmer errors without having to crash the app I have difficulty pin pointing a very good example in Swift.

Comment: @lucianomarisi You perhaps have difficulties to find a good example in Swift, because there is no such good example. If you come from C#, we would find a lot ;)   In Swift, when you do want to handle any error gracefully, you need to use Swift's `try/catch` & `throw` mechanics, which are _not_ exceptions (like in C++ or C# etc.) but is just syntactic sugar for `NSError` / `ErrorType`.